# Split a column into equal parts

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame like this

| Names | C |
| --- | --- |
| A | 000 |
| B | 000100 |
| C | XXX000100002 |

I want to split column C from left into equal parts of 3 and store it into new columns, with number of columns depended on the largest string

Output

| Names | C | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 000 | 000 | NA | NA | NA |
| B | 000100 | 000 | 100 | NA | NA |
| C | XXX000100002 | XXX | 000 | 100 | 002 |

Note: In actual dataset largest string is of length 36, so total number of columns created will be 12 for every row.

Also the dataset is huge, so a memory efficient solution would be appreciated.

Comment: please don't roll back the edit to the title, it's more or less standard here to not include the programming language in the title since it's included in the tag.

Comment: okay, first time posting a question... will keep this in mind for future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` with `(?<=...)`. Then use `[` in `lapply` to fill up columns until `max(lengths(y))`.

```
y <- strsplit(x$C, "(?<=...)", perl = TRUE)
cbind(x, do.call(rbind, lapply(y, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(y))))))
#  Names            C   1    2    3    4
#1     A          000 000 <NA> <NA> <NA>
#2     B       000100 000  100 <NA> <NA>
#3     C XXX000100002 XXX  000  100  002
```

or using `data.table::tstrsplit`.

```
do.call(cbind, data.table::tstrsplit(x$C, "(?<=...)", perl = TRUE))
```

or using `substring`.

```
n <- max(nchar(x$C))
y <- lapply(x$C, substring, seq(1, n, 3), seq(3, n, 3))
do.call(rbind, lapply(y, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(y)))))
```

or using `strsplit` with `paste`

```
y <- strsplit(x$C, "", TRUE)
y <- lapply(y, function(x) paste0(x[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)], x[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)], x[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)]))
do.call(rbind, lapply(y, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(y)))))
```

---

Benchmark:

```
bench::mark(check = FALSE
 , strsplit = {y <- strsplit(x$C, "(?<=...)", perl = TRUE)
   do.call(rbind, lapply(y, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(y)))))}
 , tstrsplit = {do.call(cbind, data.table::tstrsplit(x$C, "(?<=...)", perl = TRUE))}
 , substring = {n <- max(nchar(x$C))
   y <- lapply(x$C, substring, seq(1, n, 3), seq(3, n, 3))
   do.call(rbind, lapply(y, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(y)))))}
 , paste = {y <- strsplit(x$C, "", TRUE)
y <- lapply(y, function(x) paste0(x[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)], x[c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)], x[c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)]))
do.call(rbind, lapply(y, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(y)))))}
 , read.fwf = read.fwf(textConnection(x$C), widths = rep(3, 4), colClasses = 'character')
)
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 strsplit    27.6µs  29.5µs    32947.        0B     9.89  9997     3      303ms
#2 tstrsplit   29.3µs  31.3µs    31249.        0B     9.38  9997     3      320ms
#3 substring   74.3µs  80.8µs    12065.        0B    12.4   5850     6      485ms
#4 paste       37.1µs  40.9µs    23844.    16.4KB    14.3   9994     6      419ms
#5 read.fwf   485.2µs 514.2µs     1923.    70.9KB    15.7    611     5      318ms
```

It looks like using either `strsplit` or `tstrsplit` are fast solutions using low memory.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, if I may ask, how do I keep the original data frame intact and add these columns to it, instead of creating a new data frame?

Comment: Interesting way of using regex look behind!

Comment: @RakshitSinghal Just use cbind. See update in answer.

Comment: out of all the answers, strsplit has fastest run time!

Answer (score 0):

You can read this as a fixed width format. Since you already know the number of columns in your data, repeat 3, 12 times in `widths` to create 12 new columns.

```
df <- cbind(df, read.fwf(textConnection(df$C),
                widths = rep(3, 12), colClasses = 'character'))
df

#  Names            C  V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11  V12
#1     A          000 000 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#2     B       000100 000  100 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3     C XXX000100002 XXX  000  100  002 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: thanks Ronak, solution works but takes some time to execute.